# Cannot find sync byte m3u8 on ExoPlayer2

Tags: java, android, flutter, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a AES 128bit encrypted m3u8 playlist. I tried to host this on,

1. Google Cloud Storage Bucket via Cloudflare
2. Local Xampp server

The playlist works on HTML5 web player. Then I tried to play the m3u8 file in a Android app. I tried, A **Flutter** app, A **React Native** app and a **native Java** app

I have tried almost all the HLS libraries available for Flutter and React Native. But at the end every players shows the same error Regarding Google ExoPlayer. I'm trying to fix this for almost a month now. I have checked most of the Github issues but no luck.

This is the error I see ( Copied from the Flutter terminal but same error shows for RN and native java app, too)

```
Restarted application in 4,802ms.
I/ExoPlayerImpl(25099): Release 2354449 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [m21, SM-M215F, samsung, 30] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.hls]
I/ExoPlayerImpl(25099): Init 91918d7 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [m21, SM-M215F, samsung, 30]
6
I/System.out(25099): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:579)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: Cannot find sync byte. Most likely not a Transport Stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.findEndOfFirstTsPacketInBuffer(TsExtractor.java:453)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.read(TsExtractor.java:320)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.read(BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:434)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:404)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:355)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25099):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter (25099): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
E/flutter (25099):
```

I'll also add the content of the m3u8 file,

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://192.168.1.2/key/video.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:10.666667,
playlist0.ts
#EXTINF:11.666667,
playlist1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I see that the issue is with `TS` files since the error message show the error in `TsExtractor.java` file. Here I also tried to see the HTTP response headers of one of the TS file with curl,

```
C:\Users\mdils>curl -D - http://localhost/key/playlist0.ts
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 16:01:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
Last-Modified: Sun, 28 Feb 2021 15:29:09 GMT
ETag: "239f80-5bc6729a3ba75"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2334592
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Any help regarding this really appreciate.

**UPDATE**

Sample playlist - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q6MJNy5HT-wlMqAUmpFBvmHaCumW73Xz?usp=sharing

The FFMPEG command used for encode

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file key_info.txt playback.m3u8
```

---

**UPDATE - 2021-04-25**

Here is a working m3u8 file, ( Copied from ExoPlayer demo app )

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:9.97667,    
fileSequence0.ts
#EXTINF:9.97667,    
fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:9.97667,
...
```

Comparing this m3u8 file with the above one, the only difference is the file with the error has a aes-128 bit encrypted playlist.

Then, when I check the source code, I found this method on ExoPlayer source code,

```
  /**
   * Returns the position of the end of the first TS packet (exclusive) in the packet buffer.
   *
   * <p>This may be a position beyond the buffer limit if the packet has not been read fully into
   * the buffer, or if no packet could be found within the buffer.
   */
  private int findEndOfFirstTsPacketInBuffer() throws ParserException {
    int searchStart = tsPacketBuffer.getPosition();
    int limit = tsPacketBuffer.limit();
    int syncBytePosition =
        TsUtil.findSyncBytePosition(tsPacketBuffer.getData(), searchStart, limit);
    // Discard all bytes before the sync byte.
    // If sync byte is not found, this means discard the whole buffer.
    tsPacketBuffer.setPosition(syncBytePosition);
    int endOfPacket = syncBytePosition + TS_PACKET_SIZE;
    if (endOfPacket > limit) {
      bytesSinceLastSync += syncBytePosition - searchStart;
      if (mode == MODE_HLS && bytesSinceLastSync > TS_PACKET_SIZE * 2) {
        throw new ParserException("Cannot find sync byte. Most likely not a Transport Stream.");
      }
    } else {
      // We have found a packet within the buffer.
      bytesSinceLastSync = 0;
    }
    return endOfPacket;
  }
```

According to the comments of the above function, the above error message is thrown when it can't find the sync byte. So the only thing I can assume is maybe the player failed to decrypted the first TS file with the provided key ? ( The key is correct as this works on HLS web players )

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong with the content of the segments (`.ts` files). Are you able to share them here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @jmsn Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key file is invalid and you get garbage when decrypting the TS segments. The FFmpeg documentation for `hls_key_info_file` says:

> The key file is read as a single packed array of 16 octets in binary format

Your key file has 32 bytes. If you take the first 16 bytes of your current key file and output them in binary it will decrypt correctly. Example:

`xxd -p -l 16 video.key | xxd -r -p - video_bin.key`

Use `video_bin.key` in your playlist instead. Of course it would be better to generate a valid key in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I don't understand why it works with hls.js. Since I did not found a solution, I added a WebView with hls.js as a temporally solution.  It perfectly works in there with the 32 byte length key ( Not the same one in the question but a similar one )

Comment: @Dilshan It probably truncates the key like I did. If the player validates the key you're in trouble. For example your playlist as it is doesn't work on macOS with Safari

Comment: I just tested with the 16 byte key. It works perfectly.

Comment: why you told that it doesn't work on macOS ? because of the key ? Or  is there something else other than the segment length ?

Comment: @Dilshan Your original key had an invalid length so Safari didn't like it, unlike hls.js which just reads the first 16 bytes.

Comment: Actually I have to replace that key anyway on the front end. So I'm intercepting the requests made by the player and replace the response body with what ever I need. This works on Web and in Java ( by overriding ExoPlayer code  ) after I fixed the 32bit key to 16bit. But still the first segment request in not made to the server when trying on RN, chrome on mac os or iOS device. So it never try to replace the decryption key. What I can assume is ios or macos trying to validate my master.m3u8 file before the player even start to use it ?